# Get web service display in recyclerview and save to Favorites

Tags: android, json, sqlite, android-recyclerview, favorites

I am very new to Android , and I knw a question like this has been asked but I can't seem to understand much from the answers so I thought giving my issue I would get help ,

I am developing an app that gets json feed from Server using Retrofit, Picaso and display in a custom recyclerview and when clicking on the item it opens up a Detail activity (this I have managed to do)

Now I have Two activity one is the main which get the feed stated above and the other is myFavorites activity.

My recyclerview has a like button (heart) I would like that when a user clicks on the like button that particular recyclerview gets sent to favorites activity which also has a recyclerview

And when the user clicks the same likebutton (which will now be red ) it will turn grey and that item sent to favorites will be removed from favorites

I have seen the Shared preferences demo but I don't know if this will work with having a master/ detail activity as I would like the user to still able to click on the item that was. Sent to favorites and view the Detail activity of it

I have also come across Some saying you can save the Favorites to Sqlite and I couldn't really manage to impliment it and been stuck for two weeks now  trying every possible trick I can think of

I managed to save the whole list to Sqlite using a tutotial by (Get JSON using Retrofit2 save to DB and display it on RecyclerView ) but thats not wht I wnt , I want the user to independently save data to favorites using a like and unlike button on the recylerview

I Hope my question is understandable please someone help I have been stuck here for along time now

Comment: You can store your arraylist or custom model class to SqLite database. When you redirect to new activity retrieve that data which will return arraylist and show in recyclerview. When again hit like button check if it is already favourited ,if it is then remove from database.

Comment: Thank you for responding Piyush and if I understand you correct the array list you mean is the whole list I get from the server which I currently display in my first activity ,I should save that to Sqlite?

Comment: Yes you should !

Comment: What I want to do is save recyclerview data only on save to favorites buttonclick and I don't know how to do this

Comment: I managed to Store list into database and when hit Favorites the list is served from database Now what I want to do is not save the whole. List to Database but only one item at a time via onclick button but I can't seem to get the work around of the button to check if item is already in the database or not if. There delete if not Add

Comment: ILikeImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override                        public void onClick(View v) {  int id = (int)likeImageView.getTag();     if (id == R.drawable.heart_grey) {
                                   likeImageView.setTag(R.drawable.heart_red);
                                  likeImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
                                 Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), v.getContext().getString(R.string.added_to_favourites), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: I want to Implement such so that when a user clicks the button turns red and list item get saved to Sqlite database and on clicking again the button turns grey and item get deleted from database   Thank you